# How to plot each index value on the Y axis

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to figure out how to plot an X-axis with hourly precision (the index column has hourly values) as is in my dataframe. Currently, it just labels each month. I want one label for each Y point “close values column”.

My code now:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import dates as mpl_dates
import pandas as pd


data = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/renat/.spyder-py3/1H data new.csv', index_col=0, parse_dates=True)
data.index = pd.to_datetime(data.index, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

plt.figure(figsize=(80, 8))
plt.plot_date(data.index,data['close'], linestyle='solid',xdate=True, marker=None)
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
date_format = mpl_dates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d %H')

plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(date_format)
plt.title('Price Chart for TEST')
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Price ($)')
plt.show()
```

Comment: The following four lines should replace the three that relate to the formatting of the x-axis. `hours = mpl_dates.HourLocator(interval=1);hours_fmt = mpl_dates.DateFormatter('%H');plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(hours);plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(hours_fmt)`

Comment: @triplee thanks for the english corrections. Sorry to assassinate english. If you need any help with portuguese I would be glad to help.

Comment: @r-beginners Thank you very much! It worked but ive reached the amount limit of ticks. Either way, I know where to go now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: No immediate need, but thanks for the offer. Perhaps you could still [edit] to clarify; I don't understand what "close col" refers to here, for example (but maybe it's just lack of domain knowledge; is this financial trading data perhaps?)

Comment: It is indeed financial data. Sorry, I didn’t figured that this is a mainly code forum, not a trade one. I’m not close to pc now but I’ll fix it and also I’m gonna post my resolution.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [@r-begginers's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69112393/how-to-plot-each-index-value-on-the-y-axis/69146036#comment122151785_69112393) I am able to achieve what I want. My finished code to print financial data with hourly labels for the X axis is as follows:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import dates as mpl_dates
import pandas as pd


data = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/renat/.spyder-py3/1H data new.csv', index_col=0, parse_dates=True)
data.index = pd.to_datetime(data.index, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

plt.figure(figsize=(100, 8))
plt.plot_date(data.index,data['close'], linestyle='solid',xdate=True, marker=None)

days = mpl_dates.DayLocator(interval=1)
days_fmt = mpl_dates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(days)
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(days_fmt)

plt.grid()
plt.xticks(rotation=90, fontsize=6)
plt.title('Price Chart for TEST')
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Price ($)')
plt.show()
```

I've simply replaced the three lines that were related to the formatting of the x-axis.

In:

```py
hours = mpl_dates.HourLocator(interval=1)
hours_fmt = mpl_dates.DateFormatter('%H')
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(hours)
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(hours_fmt)
```

Out:

```py
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
date_format = mpl_dates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d %H')
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(date_format)
```

I've also made some other changes, but they are not relevant to the question.

Thanks again to @r-begginers for pointing me in this direction.